# Variable visibility in setOnClickListener

Tags: java, android, visibility, android-alertdialog

I want to disable button B when making a treatement in button A.

```
public class GoJump extends Activity{
    Button answerA, answerB;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.jump);
answerA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_A);
answerB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_B);

    answerA.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                   {
                     // Do something
                     // Disable button B
                   }
    });
```

The problem is button B is not visible inside button A treatement. I have to declare it another time to disable it.
Is there any other method to do? Make a variable visible in all class.
Thank you.

Comment: Make it as instance and final variable instead of local variable. More code would help.

Comment: @Nambari: I just want to disable button B when taping on button A. Just it ;). Any code please?

Comment: Without seeing your code (how you declared Button B), it is hard to give an example. Please provide more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your variable before onCreate().

```
// Before onCreate
private Button b, b2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                b2.setEnabled(false);
            }
    });
{
```

Comment: Yep yep yep that works now ;). Cause: Eclipse! Thank you dude :).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to `setEnabled` to false.  Read this [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html).

```
          public void onClick(View v) 
                   {
                     answerB.setEnabled(false);
                   }
```

Comment: b is not visible inside the onClick

Comment: Sorry! it should be answerB. Updated answer.

Comment: What a joke that Eclipse! It mades me crazy! I just restarted it and know it see answerB variable! I know that it's not logical but had to post a question to be sure. Thank you man ;)

Comment: @androniennn: Good to know. Enjoy coding.

Comment: You have a good reputation, so i'll give the answer button to Artyom Kiriliyk if you permit. Thank you anyway :) :)

Comment: @androniennn: Nothing like permission to ask. Who ever you wish for.